# Where is the keyboard definition file for a custom input source?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Somewhere back in time (and possibly in a galaxy far far away) I had added an Input Source to my OS/X mavericks.  I believe I have located the file that was used as the definition. However, it is not clear from the Keyboard | Input Sources dialog how to (a) view the properties of the custom Input Source or (b) edit / update an existing Input Source

So how to update/edit MAC keyboard input source definition file?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation the location is

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Keyboard Layouts/MyLayout.keylayout
```

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard layout file can be in a user's Library/Keyboard Layouts/ or in the system's Library/Keyboard Layouts/

Most people use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to create custom keyboard layouts.  See [superuser #665494](https://superuser.com/questions/665494/how-to-make-a-custom-keyboard-layout-in-macos) for more hints.

Answer (score -1):

According to Apple http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14056 (reproduced the salient part below in case the link breaks)

**Create a custom input source**

1. Open TextEdit or another text editor.
2. Create your rule file using the sample file below as a guideline. The file must be a plain text file. If necessary, choose Format > Make Plain Text in TextEdit or your text editor.
3. Save the file (the name will appear in the Input menu and the Input Sources pane), with an extension such as “.inputplugin” or “.cin.”
4. Double-click the saved file. Your custom input source is added to the Input menu (looks like a flag or character) in the menu bar, and to the list of input sources in the Input Sources pane in Keyboard preferences.

Comment: Yes I saw that. But it does not answer the OP - that is, *after* having created an input source - how to view its properties and change them.

Comment: Edit the original file. Replace the input source with the newly edited file.

Comment: I am uncertain of what is the path/ contents of the *existing* Input Source.  That is the first part of the question: how to view the properties of the Input Source.